# gitignore doesn't work in my case

Tags: git, github

I created .gitignore and within it I put `config/db.js` because I want to connect to my localhost db, but still when I change the file db.js in config folder git still track the changes.

Comment: Can you please share your full `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @Mureinik just one line which is `config/db.js`

Comment: Were you already tracking it before you added it to the ignore file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. am I doing it wrong? I assume if it's tracked and I add it into `.gitignore` and it will become untrack, no?

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I git pull the config/db.js came back to my local dev. dang! what's wrong?

Comment: *"The removal of the file from the head revision will happen on the next commit"* - you actually need to *push* the removal and ignoring.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
git rm --cached config/db.js
```

Comment: but when I pull the file come back again to my local. why?

Comment: After you execute the above command, commit your change, and push to your git repository. Then the remote file should be removed.

Comment: I don't want the file to be removed